# What happens if a Salesforce field referenced in a Journey Builder as an Event data is removed or deleted in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I am using a Salesforce field in a Journey while setting up the Event data. However, in future that field might be moved to a different object. What happens to the journey in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

1. All Contacts in the journey can complete the journey and using the data inside the journey is possible **as long as you only use Journey Data** (formerly known as Event Data) as this always represents the value at journey entry time.
2. For new journey entries you need to create a new journey version with an entry event that works with the updated field location as the old entry event won't work properly after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new version of the journey with the field referencing the new object location.